# How prove this $F'(x_{0})=f(x_{0})$ if $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt,x\in[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, derivatives

**Question:**

let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$,Assmue that $x_{0}\in [a,b]$,and let $f(x)$ is continuous on point $x=x_{0}$,and define
$$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt,x\in[a,b]$$

show that
$$F'(x_{0})=f(x_{0})$$

This problem is my friend (He is a teacher) ask me,and I post my answer,maybe have some wrong,

> since
>   $$F'(x_{0})=\lim_{x\to x_{0}}\dfrac{F(x)-F(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=\lim_{x\to x_{0}}\dfrac{\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)dt}{x-x_{0}}$$
>   and other hand,

case1: $x>x_{0}$ we have

> $$I=\left|\dfrac{\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)dt}{x-x_{0}}-f(x_{0})\right|=\dfrac{\left|\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)dt-f(x_{0})(x-x_{0})\right|}{x-x_{0}}\le\dfrac{\int_{x_{0}}^{x}|f(t)-f(x_{0})|dt}{x-x_{0}}$$
>   since
>   $f(x)$ is continous on point $x=x_{0}$
>   so
>   $$I\le\dfrac{\int_{x_{0}}^{x}\varepsilon dt}{x-x_{0}}=\varepsilon$$
>   so
>   $$F'(x_{0})=f(x_{0})$$

case2:$x<x_{0}$

> $$I=\left|\dfrac{\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)dt}{x-x_{0}}-f(x_{0})\right|=\dfrac{\left|\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)dt-f(x_{0})(x-x_{0})\right|}{|x-x_{0}|}\le\dfrac{\int_{x}^{x_{0}}|f(t)-f(x_{0})|dt}{x_{0}-x}$$
>   since
>   $f(x)$ is continous on point $x=x_{0}$
>   so
>   $$I\le\dfrac{\int_{x}^{x_{0}}\varepsilon dt}{x_{0}-x}=\varepsilon$$

**My question:  someone  have other methods? Thank you  very much!**

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and quite possibly the simplest way to prove this.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan,I think so,I hope see other.Thank you

Comment: As written, you need $x > x_0$ for the inequalities. To also treat $x < x_0$, you need to take the absolute value of $x-x_0$, and in the last inequality, also of the integral ($\int_{x_0}^x \varepsilon\,dx < 0$ for $x < x_0$).

Comment: Oh,Thank you @DanielFischer,I edit it,Now is true?

Comment: Yes, now all cases are covered.

Comment: @DanielFischer,But when $x=x_{0}$ How deal it?

Comment: For the derivative, you consider the difference quotient. $x \neq x_0$ is a prerequisite for forming it, the case $x = x_0$ does not occur.

Comment: @math110  Can i use **Laplace transformation** ?

Comment: @sonu,Yes, you can.can you post your Laplace transformation?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

We can use Leibniz integral rule for variable limit

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)dt$$ =

$$f(g(x)).h'(x)-f(h(x)).g'(x)$$

We have

$$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt,x\in[a,b]$$

Therefore  $$\frac{d}{dx}F(x) =f(x) $$
and $$ F'(x)=f(x) $$

so 
$$F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$$

Comment: No,This methods is wrong!

Comment: Why this method is wrong ?

Comment: $F(x)$ Not necessarily can derivative

Comment: If **derivative** of F(x) is **not** Possible then how can you get $F'(x_0)$ ?

Comment: Okay.... here's the issue.  The OPs English is poor, so he uses $F'(x_0)$ but doesn't mean to say that he really wants to show its existence.  If you look at @Jonathan Y.'s answer you will see he makes an argument of the existence of the derivative by directly computing it using the limit definition (using limsup and liminf).  ##The problem is with the OP not you.##

Comment: sonu, there's a distinction between knowing a function isn't differentiable at a point and not knowing whether it is (the second necessitating a proof). Put differently, OP's question was proof verification/finding distinct methods of proof for a special case of Leibniz's formula; citing the full-blown version to solve the question is counterproductive.

Comment: @sonu: the problem is that the function $f(x)$ is not continuous in the whole of $[a,b]$, thus $F(x)$ might not be derivative in other points.

Comment: @Farshad If function is continuous at $x =x_0$ than it's not guarantee that $F'(x_0)$ exist or not .So how you can find $F'(x_0)$ ?

Comment: @sonu here $f(x)$ is Riemman integrable in $[a,b]$. According to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if it is integrable in the whole of $[a,b]$ then $F$ is derivative in $(a,b)$ but the problem is that we know it is only integrable in one point.

Comment: It's good but what about $F(x_0)$ at $x= x_0$ ?

Comment: @sonu; I don't have any answer now in my hand, but the answer of Jonathan seems to be good that I had a problem with, and I have written a comment on his answer.

Comment: sonu, the point, I think, was that you only have continuity at $x_0$ (although you must naturally assume integrability over $[a,b]$ just to be able to define $F$). @FarshadNahangi, the fundamental th. works in its usual phrasing if $f$ is *continuous* in $[a,b]$; integrability isn't enough for differentiability of $F$. Here, we only know *continuity* at one point; we must assume integrability in $[a,b]$ (which, by Lebesgue, gives us continuity a.e., but that's beside the point).

Comment: Oops, that was my mistake I was trying to say that it is continuous in one point as mentioned in the question, and while assumed function is integrable in [a,b], I wrote integrable only in one point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this amounts to a different approach, but:

Building on the fact that if $f:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable (this is actually important; one must know that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ to define $F$ as above) and non-negative (i.e., $f(x)\geq 0$) then $\int_c^d f(x)dx\geq 0$ as well, we note that for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$
$$\inf_{|t-x_0|<\epsilon} f(t)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\epsilon} f(t)dt\leq\sup_{|t-x_0|<\epsilon} f(t),$$
and similarly
$$\inf_{|t-x_0|<\epsilon} f(t)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0} f(t)dt\leq\sup_{|t-x_0|<\epsilon} f(t).$$

Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, we know that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\inf_{|t-x_0|<\epsilon} f(t) = f(x_0) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\sup_{|t-x_0|<\epsilon} f(t),$$
implying that
$$\exists\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{F(x_0+\epsilon)-F(x_0)}{\epsilon} = f(x_0).$$

Comment: nice; Where does the question say that f is non-negative, and more important where did you use of this fact in your proof?

Comment: @FarshadNahangi, it's not $f$ that's non-negative, but $x\mapsto(\sup_{t}f(t)-f(x))$ and $x\mapsto(f(x)-\inf_{t}f(t))$, and we use the positiveness of the integral in establishing the inequalities (note the factor derived from the length of the interval).

Answer (score 0):

That's correct but assumes $a$ and $f$ are fixed.

Just to challenge your friend, you can prove with the same argument that if 
$$F(x)=\int_x^b f(t)dt,x∈[a,b]$$
then
$$F'(x_0)=-f(x_0), x \in [a,b].$$